# Can someone kill Rama or Ravaan or Krishna?

Tags: rebirth

Since hinduism believes in transmigration of souls, if someone kills a chicken or sheep or mosquito, is it possible one has killed ram or raavan or krishna?

Comment: Lord Rama and Krishna are not ordinary souls. They are in fact super-soul. Anyone get the life of insects, animals because of their bad Karma. And Ravana is also one of the gatekeeper of Lord Vishnu and had only three births as Rakshasa.

Comment: Proof for super soul, how can a super soul be born to ordinary soul

Comment: Search for incarnation on this site. You will get basic idea.

Comment: @AbdulMuqitshaik they have already left the earth ... how will someone kill ??

Comment: Where is the proof that souls of ram and krishna have left earth?

Comment: These questions about proof cannot be answered by any Religion.

Answer (score 2):

Transformation of soul is nothing but transforming of energy into other form, in Hinduism,is the oldest form of religion as compared to other religions which are just 2 to 3 thousands years old, which previously dominated by Rishis as oldest form of scientists in every area, they described the complex things or topics in easy and understandable meanings, they know the truth of life hence they created meanings to describe it to common people, now imagine ten thousand years back in time, people of that period, who were believed in supernatural power, would not like to listen the truth, hence Rishis described in religious manner,all the things which was described in religious books were not in the same meaning. but they have meanings in other form, it is up to you which meaning you like as per your knowledge of nature.
In Hinduism, The great Rishis know that all the life on earth is created by Sun energy, hence they started the day with Surya Namaskar ( Giving thanks to Sun i,e. the father of all energy) and they also worship Shiva as the the true energy, because all the planets, sun, stars and matters you see in the universe are form of energy, it is the ultimate source of life and universe, so if you want to understand it you have to leave the religion aside and because just saying all is created by god/allah or some other supper power mean s you do not want to understand the Nature.

Comment: Be specific (on topic / to the point) while answering questions, avoid commenting. Visit [answer] and cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone who's born has to die someday. That's the general rule for the creation.

Regarding the question, on killing

1. Ravana

- Sri Rama killed Ravana, described as follows in the Book 6:

> [Sarga 108](https://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/yuddha/sarga108/yuddha_108_frame.htm), Yuddha Kanda, Valmiki Ramayan
>
> स रावणाय संक्रुद्धो भृशमायम्य कार्मुकम् | चिक्षेप परमायत्तः शरं
> मर्मविदारणम् || ६-१०८-१६
>
> > 16. That enraged Rama, stretching his bow well and with an attentive mind, hurled that arrow which can tear off the vitals, towards Ravana.
>
> .....
>
> रुधिराक्तह् स वेगेन शरीरान्तकरः शरः | रावणस्य हरन् प्राणान् विवेश
> धरणीतलम् || ६-१०८-१९
>
> > 19. That arrow, which was capable of causing death to the body, after taking away the life of Ravana and having been anointed with blood,
> >     penetrated the earth.

So, yes Ravana can be killed. As we see, he was killed by the God himself.

---

2. Sri Rama

- Rama took the Mahaprasthana via jala-samadhi as per his own volition.

> [Chapter 110](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424885.html), Uttara-kanda, Valmiki Ramayan
>
> At that moment, as Kakutstha was preparing to ascend to heaven,
> Brahma, the Grandsire of the World, surrounded by the Gods
>
> ....
>
> Hearing these words of the Grandsire, the supremely virtuous Rama
> formed his resolution and entered Vishnu’s abode in his body with his
> younger brothers.

So we see, Sri Rama "ascended" from the Earth not via normal "mortal-means", but through his own volition.

---

3. Sri Krishna

Krishna was killed by a hunter named Jara -

> ŚB 11.30.33
>
> मुषलावशेषाय:खण्डकृतेषुर्लुब्धको जरा । मृगास्याकारं तच्चरणं विव्याध
> मृगशङ्कया ॥
>
> > Just then a hunter named Jarā, who had approached the place, mistook
> > the Lord’s foot for a deer’s face. Thinking he had found his prey,
> > Jarā pierced the foot with his arrow, which he had fashioned from the
> > remaining iron fragment of Sāmba’s club.

So, we see Krishna was killed by the hunter Jara. So yes, it's possible to kill the apparently human Krishna.

However, a very important thing to note is that it was Krishna's own lila (लीला) to do so, unlike the normal humans, Krishna is God, so he (Vishnu) himself chooses how he will descend and ascend with his incarnations, as Krishna himself says in the [ŚB 10.89.57](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/89/57/), after being hit by the arrow from the hunter -

> **What has been done is actually My own desire**. With My permission, go now to the abode of the pious, the spiritual world.

So, yeah, we may conclude that Ravana can be killed, as he was rightly killed by Sri Rama. For gods like Rama and Krishna, who are avatars of Vishnu or their own Supreme selves, they themselves choose their destiny, and especially their way of leaving their human mortal coils, unlike normal beings.